# Quarkus Rest client JSON serialization: equivalent of @JsonIgnore to ignore some field in serialization

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

How to ignore a field in a Quarkus Rest Client request body? I see in the dependency tree, this is listed:

```
io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb:jar:2.7.5.Final:compile
```

And using `@JsonIgnore` or `JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` is not working.

I guess it is because `MessageBodyWriter` is using Jsonb providers, not Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb` instead of `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson`, you need to use [JSON-B](https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/) annotations.
In this case, you would use `javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbTransient`

Comment: I tested and it works. Good! I know Jsonb has basic functionality like this which would save a lot of code. I wonder why this is not in Quarkus doc. Actually a link to the Jsonb site and a small example would be just enough.

Comment: Feel to free to open an issue or even contribute adding a link to the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

Check here: https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_json_p_and_json_b_providers

Basically, you need to register a provider to config things for your rest client(but I think this is bad if you have a lot of fields to ignore).

My impl:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import javax.json.bind.config.PropertyVisibilityStrategy;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;

public class EventJsonbCustomizer implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {

    @Override
    public Jsonb getContext(Class<?> type) {
        JsonbConfig jsonbConfig = new JsonbConfig()
                .withPropertyVisibilityStrategy(new PropertyVisibilityStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean isVisible(Field field) {
                        return !field.getDeclaringClass().equals(Event.class) ||
                                !field.getName().equals("package"); // if is this class and this field, return false; else true
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean isVisible(Method method) {
                        return false; // always false
                    }
                });
        return JsonbBuilder.newBuilder().withConfig(jsonbConfig).build();
    }
}
```

And the rest client:

```java
@ApplicationScoped // needed for @QuarkusTest injection
@Path("")
@RegisterProvider(EventJsonbCustomizer.class)
public interface EventSenderRestAPI extends AutoCloseable {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response create(@HeaderParam(AUTHORIZATION) String authorization, Event event);

...
```

Strange, strange way of doing things. But at last it works.